# Why do casting a hex int to a char* prints it backwards?

Tags: c, casting

I thought I understood how memory works until I run this code, is memory backwards ? or I'm missing something ?

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0x12345678;

    char *c = (char *)&a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("c[%d]=%x \n", i, *(c + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
c[0]=78

c[1]=56

c[2]=34

c[3]=12
```

Comment: You're on a little-endian machine.  Compare what happens if you start with `short a[2] = { 0x1234, 0x5678 }` and leave everything else the same.

Comment: This is a common FAQ. [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have just done is demonstrate which "endian" your computer's architecture is using (i.e., your computer uses "little endian", not "big endian").

If your computer's architecture had instead been "big endian", then your output would instead have been this:

```
c[0] = 12
c[1] = 34
c[2] = 56
c[3] = 78
```

You may want to read this for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the *endianness* of your machine. Check [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

> A big-endian system stores the most significant byte of a word at the
> smallest memory address and the least significant byte at the largest.
> A little-endian system, in contrast, stores the least-significant byte
> at the smallest address.

Your machine is *little-endian*.